# Creating a trend streak in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create trend streak that displays 1,-1,0 (win/loss/no movement) from a pandas database. I'm looking for the streak to increase when positive, and reset on 0, or reset and create a negative streak on -1. The desired results would be something like this:

```
win  streak
0    0
1    1
1    2
1    3
1    4
0    0
0    0
-1   -1
-1   -2
1    1
```

Currently I have this that creates the win column.

```
dataframe.loc[dataframe['close'] > dataframe['close_1h'].shift(1), 'win'] = 1
dataframe.loc[dataframe['close'] < dataframe['close_1h'].shift(1), 'win'] = -1
dataframe.loc[dataframe['close'] == dataframe['close_1h'].shift(1), 'win'] = 0
dataframe['streak'] = numpy.nan_to_num(dataframe['win'].cumsum())
```

But that doesn't correctly reset the streaks as I would like it to. I've played around with the groupby doing `dataframe['streak'] = dataframe.groupby([(dataframe['win'] != dataframe['win'].shift()).cumsum()])` but that gave me an error resulting in "ValueError: Length of values (927) does not match length of index (1631)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df['streak'] = df.groupby(df['win'].diff().ne(0).cumsum())['win'].cumsum()
```